# How to connect two services in the same stack network?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network, docker-stack

I have docker-compose.yaml file like:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  passbolt:
    image: passbolt/passbolt
    hostname: passbolt
    container_name: passbolt
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    environment:
      DATASOURCES_DEFAULT_HOST: mariadb
      DATASOURCES_DEFAULT_USERNAME: passbolt
      DATASOURCES_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: passbolt
      DATASOURCES_DEFAULT_DATABASE: passbolt
      APP_FULL_BASE_URL: https://my.url/
    networks:
      - passbolt_network
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    hostname: mariadb
    container_name: mariadb
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: passbolt
      MYSQL_USER: passbolt
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: passbolt
    networks:
      - passbolt_network
networks:
  passbolt_network:
    driver: overlay
```

I'm runnig stack by `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yaml test`
And **passbolt** service is exited because of *Exception: There was a problem connecting to the database: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused in (...)*

Comment: try removing the container_name from both. actually this works.

Comment: what is ip and port of mariadb passbolt service tries to connect to?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use network aliases :

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  passbolt:
    image: passbolt/passbolt
    hostname: passbolt
    container_name: passbolt
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    environment:
      DATASOURCES_DEFAULT_HOST: alias_to_mariadb
      DATASOURCES_DEFAULT_USERNAME: passbolt
      DATASOURCES_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: passbolt
      DATASOURCES_DEFAULT_DATABASE: passbolt
      APP_FULL_BASE_URL: https://my.url/
    networks:
      - passbolt_network
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    hostname: mariadb
    container_name: mariadb
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: passbolt
      MYSQL_USER: passbolt
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: passbolt
    networks:
      passbolt_network:
        aliases:
          - "alias_to_mariadb"
networks:
  passbolt_network:
    driver: overlay
```